# Android better implementation of fragments for navigation

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-navigation

I have a navigationview and draw layout for my app and I'm switching between views using fragments. I currently have it implemented like this and it works fine:

app_bar_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I set the initial fragment when the app first launches in `onCreate` of my `MainActivity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    //Provide global access to navigationview and toolbar
    NavigationView navigationView = null;
    Toolbar toolbar = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Set initial fragment
        NewFragment fragment = new NewFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
...
```

And when a user selects a menu item I set swap out the fragment like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_new) {
            NewFragment fragment = new NewFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_start) {
            StartFragment fragment = new StartFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
...
```

I feel like I have a lot of redundant code in the initial fragment set, as well as in the if statements

What is a better way to condense that code and swap out fragments without being repetitive like this?

Comment: you can add      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new StartFragment());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call these method in navigation drawer with just the new object of your fragment

```
    @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.search_near) {
              addNewFragmentWithBackStack(new FragmentOne());
           }else if(.....){
              addNewFragmentWithBackStack(new FragmentTwo());
           }
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;

    }
```

For adding fragment with backstack

```
public void addNewFragmentWithBackStack(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .commit();
    } else {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function as below and pass a fragment object as a parameter:

```
private void launchActivity(Fragement fragment)
{
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Now just create an object and call this function wherever you need.
It will avoid the repetition of the code.